# how to check process id or process of scheduled job

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

can we check process id or process of scheduled cronjob script

let say, I have scheduled one script "abc.sh" which runs all time and I have scheduled it crontab like below -
* * * * 0-5 script.sh

Once I schedule, I know it will keep running but can I check process status whether "script.sh" is running or not

Answer (score 1):

Use `pgrep` or `pidof`:

```
pgrep script.sh
```

Comment: Hi @Ipor, it's not working. for ex. I have scheduled new one script in crontab to send report every 15 minutes that means there IS A PROCESS which is running & I'm getting report for every 15 min but doing "pidof" or "pgrep" for above script couldn't find any process id associated with it